# transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/github/mikephil/charting/animation/ChartAnimator.class

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.journaldev.navigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':MPChartLib')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problem related to the SDK cache.
**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Try  - Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.

More information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)